# Memory Profiling on DataTable memory size

Tags: c#, memory, datatable, memory-profiling

I have done a memory profiling on my application here trying to find out how much memory the datatable has consumed on my application.

However, can someone tell me how to find out the size of the datatable?

[image]

Do i just read from the DataTable type instance? Or should i add up the size of everything (e.g: DataRowCollection,DataColumnCollection, DataTable, etc)?

Thank you.

Comment: What tool are you using that gives you that report?

Comment: If you are using the Diagnostic Tools View from VS, you can take a snapshot and review your DataTable instance and see its properties, like size

Comment: This is the diagnostic tools from VS itself, yes i have took a base snapshot and snapshot after creating my DataTable instance, the screenshot provided are the comparison of both snapshot

Comment: So are you suggesting that i can just review on the DataTable instance itself ? And the DataRowCollection, DataColumnCollection are included in the DataTable instance itself right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Diagnostic tools View of VS, take a snapshot of you application:

[image: Snapshot]

then, click the objects diff link:,

[image: objects diff link]

In the snapshot tab, there is a filter input, where you filter by type name, enter "DataTable", then click in the "view instances of datatable" button:

[image: Snapshot tab]

in the next screen, you view the instance or instances of your datatable instance. The Inclusive Size give you the full size of your object:

[image: size of object]

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage-without-debugging2?view=vs-2019):

> Inclusive Size (Bytes):   The size of the instances of the type, or the
>   size of a single instance, including the size of contained objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the detailed explanation and even the steps-by-steps screenshot. Really appreciate it!